# Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()

Tags: java, string, replace

What's the difference between java.lang.String 's `replace()` and `replaceAll()` methods,
other than the latter uses regex? For simple substitutions like, replace `.` with `/`, is there any difference?

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/f35750c5d63f5df4d31322b372e25c01696028df) commit.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

- In [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), the `replace` method either takes a pair of char's or a pair of `CharSequence`'s (which String is implementing, so it'll happily take a pair of String's). The `replace` method will replace all occurrences of a char or `CharSequence`.
- On the other hand, the first  `String` arguments of `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` are regular expressions (regex).

Using the wrong function can lead to subtle bugs.

---

Relevant sections from [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

- `String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`
  Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.
- `String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`
  Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.
- `String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`
  Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
- `String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`
  Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Comment: In addition, according to java docs, each call to `str.replaceAll(regex, repl)` is same as `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)`. So there is a big overhead depending on how much it's used.

Comment: @user845279 It's interesting you would say that since `String#replace(target, replacement)` does the same thing, except it quotes the strings: `Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));` Is there some reason why `String#replace` would be faster than `String#replaceAll`? It wouldn't seem like it since `String#replace` just performs additional operations.

Comment: Just curious, in this answer where is the explicit comparison against `replaceAll`. The answer is more about `replace`

Comment: this means replaceAll() would be costlier due to regex match?isn't it ?

Answer (score 159):

Just the regex.  They both **replace all** :)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

PS:

There's also a `replaceFirst()` (which takes a regex)

Comment: Thx for the clarification that it is just the regex. How i wish they had named it replaceWithRegex() instead of replaceAll()

Comment: **Clarification:** replaceAll() works with regular expressions, replace() works with CharSequence

Comment: @JohnnyFive That makes it more confusing. Regular expression is not a type, `CharSequence` is. Both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` "work with `CharSequence`". It's that `replaceAll()` considers the given `CharSequence` as a regular expression so it looks for _regex matches_, while `replace()` considers the given `CharSequence` as a plain search text so it looks for _occurrences_ of it.

Comment: both replace All ! thats what i wanted to hear !

Answer (score 85):

Both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` replace all occurrences in the String.

## Examples

I always find examples helpful to understand the differences.

## [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Use `replace()` if you just want to replace some `char` with another `char` or some `String` with another `String` (actually `CharSequence`).

**Example 1**

Replace all occurrences of the character `x` with `o`.

```
String myString = "__x___x___x_x____xx_";

char oldChar = 'x';
char newChar = 'o';

String newString = myString.replace(oldChar, newChar);
// __o___o___o_o____oo_
```

**Example 2**

Replace all occurrences of the string `fish` with `sheep`.

```
String myString = "one fish, two fish, three fish";

String target = "fish";
String replacement = "sheep";

String newString = myString.replace(target, replacement);
// one sheep, two sheep, three sheep
```

## [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Use `replaceAll()` if you want to use a [regular expression pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

**Example 3**

Replace any number with an `x`.

```
String myString = "__1_6____3__6_345____0";

String regex = "\\d";
String replacement = "x";

String newString = myString.replaceAll(regex, replacement); 
// __x_x____x__x_xxx____x
```

**Example 4**

Remove all whitespace.

```
String myString = "   Horse         Cow\n\n   \r Camel \t\t Sheep \n Goat        ";

String regex = "\\s";
String replacement = "";

String newString = myString.replaceAll(regex, replacement); 
// HorseCowCamelSheepGoat
```

## See also

Documentation

- [`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))
- [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))
- [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
- [`replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://replaceFirst(String%20regex,%20String%20replacement))

Regular Expressions

- [Tutorial](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/)
- [List of patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Answer (score 43):

The `replace()` method is overloaded to accept both a primitive `char` and a `CharSequence` as arguments.

Now as far as the performance is concerned, the `replace()` method is a bit faster than `replaceAll()` because the latter first compiles the regex pattern and then matches before finally replacing whereas the former simply matches for the provided argument and replaces.

Since we know the regex pattern matching is a bit more complex and consequently slower, then preferring `replace()` over `replaceAll()` is suggested whenever possible.

For example, for simple substitutions like you mentioned, it is better to use:

```
replace('.', '\\');
```

instead of:

```
replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\");
```

Note: the above conversion method arguments are system-dependent.

Comment: Even replace also do the same, From java String docs ::

**public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
        return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
    }**

Comment: @Prateek: after jdk8, String::replace is not using Pattern anymore : https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2152 , same in  jdk11.

Comment: Agree, In Java **8** practically both methods are _almost_ the same, for both appear the `Pattern.compile(...)` content/part in their implementations, seems `replace` is less complex about how to define/send the first argument. It does not require `"\"` . Furthermore `replace` is available since Java `1.5` and `replaceAll` since `1.4`

Answer (score 7):

1. Both replace() and replaceAll() accepts two arguments and replaces all occurrences of the first substring(first argument) in a string with the second substring (second argument).
2. replace() accepts a pair of char or charsequence and replaceAll() accepts a pair of regex.
3. It is not true that replace() works faster than replaceAll() since both uses the same code in its implementation

   Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);

Now the question is when to use replace and when to use replaceAll().
When you want to replace a substring with another substring regardless of its place of occurrence in the string use replace(). But if you have some particular preference or condition like replace only those substrings at the beginning or end of a string use replaceAll(). Here are some examples to prove my point:

```
String str = new String("==qwerty==").replaceAll("^==", "?"); \\str: "?qwerty=="
String str = new String("==qwerty==").replaceAll("==$", "?"); \\str: "==qwerty?"
String str = new String("===qwerty==").replaceAll("(=)+", "?"); \\str: "?qwerty?"
```

Comment: They are not the exact same implementation. `replace` doesn't call `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);`. It calls `Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));`

Comment: _replaceAll() accepts a pair of regex_ Why would both the search string **and the replacement string** be a regex? What would the occurrences be replaced with? With a regex? Of course only the first argument is a regex (the search string). The second one is not a regex (the replacement string).

Answer (score 4):

To throw more light with an example into how both are going to work for below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "My\\s aaab\\s is\\s aaab\\s name";
    String s1 = s.replace("\\s", "c");
    System.out.println(s1);
    String s2 = s.replaceAll("\\s", "c");
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Myc aaabc isc aaabc name
My\scaaab\scis\scaaab\scname
```

**Explanation**

s.replace replaces "\\s" sequence of characters with c. Hence, the output in first line.
s.replaceAll considers \\s as a regex rather(equivalent to space) and replaces spaces with c. \\s in String s is escaped with first \ encountered and becomes \s.

Intellij Idea is smart enough to notify you of the usage as well. If you take a closer look at below image, you will see the difference in interpretation by Intellij idea for replace and replaceAll usage.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

```
String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement
```

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread I know but I am sort of new to Java and discover one of it's strange things. I have used `String.replaceAll()` but get unpredictable results.

Something like this mess up the string:

```
sUrl = sUrl.replaceAll( "./", "//").replaceAll( "//", "/");
```

So I designed this function to get around the weird problem:

```
//String.replaceAll does not work OK, that's why this function is here
public String strReplace( String s1, String s2, String s ) 
{
    if((( s == null ) || (s.length() == 0 )) || (( s1 == null ) || (s1.length() == 0 )))
     { return s; }

   while( (s != null) && (s.indexOf( s1 ) >= 0) )
    { s = s.replace( s1, s2 ); }
  return s;
}
```

Which make you able to do:

```
sUrl=this.strReplace("./", "//", sUrl );
sUrl=this.strReplace( "//", "/", sUrl );
```

Comment: `String.replaceAll()` expects [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) not literal arguments, which is why you get "unpredictable" (which are really very much predictable) results. `String.replace()` works the way you want.

Comment: As a rule of thumb for when we get unexpected results from Java, rather than designing a new function to get around that, it's better to assume that those results are dead right and that we are misunderstanding the Java functionality we are using.

Comment: I understand that replaceAll uses regex .. but this simple function strReplace fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in wickeD's answer, with replaceAll the replacement string is handled differently between replace and replaceAll.  I expected a[3] and a[4] to have the same value, but they are different.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = new String[5];
    a[0] = "\\";
    a[1] = "X";
    a[2] = a[0] + a[1];
    a[3] = a[1].replaceAll("X", a[0] + "X");
    a[4] = a[1].replace("X", a[0] + "X");

    for (String s : a) {
        System.out.println(s + "\t" + s.length());
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
\   1
X   1
\X  2
X   1
\X  2
```

This is different from perl where the replacement does not require the extra level of escaping:

```
#!/bin/perl
$esc = "\\";
$s = "X";

$s =~ s/X/${esc}X/;
print "$s " . length($s) . "\n";
```

which prints
\X 2

This can be quite a nuisance, as when trying to use the value returned by java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getSearchStringEscape() with replaceAll().

Answer (score 1):

From Java 9 there is some optimizations in replace method.

In Java 8 it uses a regex.

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

From Java 9 and on.

[image]

And Stringlatin implementation.

[image]

Which perform way better.

https://medium.com/madhash/composite-pattern-in-a-nutshell-ad1bf78479cc?source=post_internal_links---------2------------------

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` method doesn't uses regex pattern whereas `replaceAll()` method uses regex pattern. So `replace()` performs faster than `replaceAll()`.

Comment: thats not true. If you look at the source of replace you will see it also used the Pattern and Matcher (ie regex)

Comment: From Java 9 this is true.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already selected "Best Answer" (and others that are just as good like Suragch's), `String.replace()` is constrained by replacing characters that are sequential (thus taking `CharSequence`). However, `String.replaceAll()` is not constrained by replacing sequential characters only. You could replace non-sequential characters as well as long as your regular expression is constructed in such a way.

Also (most importantly and painfully obvious), `replace()` can only replace literal values; whereas `replaceAll` can replace 'like' sequences (not necessarily identical).

Answer (score -5):

replace works on char data type but replaceAll works on String datatype and both replace the all occurrences of first argument with second argument.