# Replacing a string with substring of that string

Tags: java, replace

In Java I have a String

```
String string = "sdfgjhjdfg.m\"gb=1234509876\"xcvbnfghj".
```

I want to replace it with `Hi="1234509876"`.

In string replace function i could not do this.

```
string = string.replace(".*gb=(.*)\".*","Hi=(.*)");
```

In the 2nd parameter `(.*)` group, the group in 1st parameters should get replace
Please Help me....

Comment: You want "replaceAll". "replace" does not use regular expressions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-java-string-replace-and-replaceall

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code for getting number string from main string

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String string = "sdfgjhjdfg.m\"gb=1234509876\"xcvbnfghj";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
        while (m.find()) {
          string=m.group();
        }
        System.out.println("res"+string);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    String string = "sdfgjhjdfg.m\"gb=1234509876\"xcvbnfghj";
    String newStr=string.replaceAll("gb=1234509876","Hi=1234509876");
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string = string.replace("gb=","Hi=");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String string = "sdfgjhjdfg.m\"gb=1234509876\"xcvbnfghj";
System.out.println(string);
string = string.replaceAll("gb=-?\\d+","Hi='new value'");
System.out.println(string);
```