# Trim string issue with android Spinner

Tags: android, string, trim

I have a spinner listener where I get the selection String. I need simply to remove all blank spaces, but strangely the trim() function doesn't work

```
OnItemSelectedListener mGradoListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String selection= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            System.out.println("Selection is: " + selection);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

The original String is `"Predective Value Positive"` or whatever string in *strings.xml* with a blankspace
The result string is the same.

the spinner uses a string array saved in the android values `strings.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need simply to remove all blank spaces, but strangely the trim()
>   function doesn't work´

[`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) function removes space(s) only at beginning and ending of String e.q.

```
String s =  "   Hello buddy ";
```

Output `->` `[   Hello buddy ]` ... with `trim()` `->` `[Hello buddy]`

So if you want to remove exactly all spaces (also between words) you need to use something like this:

```
s.replace(" ", "");
```

**Note:** If you need to use some regular epression, use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll()) method.
Difference between both you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-java-string-replace-and-replaceall).