# Jsoup converting & to &amp; when I require that info as it is

Tags: java, jsoup

In few cases I pass JSON having the page url on which user performed some action. That page url will have those query string part which I need that for user to redirect to same page when required from my application. my JSON will be like

```
{
"userId":"123456789",
"pageUrl":"http://exampl.com/designs.jsp?templateId=f348aaf2-45e4-4836-9be4-9a7e63105932&kind=123",
"action":"favourite"
}
```

But when I run this json through `Jsoup.clean(json, Whitelist.basic())` I see that `&` been replaced with `&amp;`. Can I configure `Jsoup` to not to escape this character alone?

Comment: Have you tried any of the other Whitelist options, like [`relaxed`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#relaxed())?

Comment: even with relaxed I see same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workround after applying `Jsoup.clean()` I am replacing `&amp;` with `&` using `regex`.

```
String url = Jsoup.clean(url, Whitelist.basic()).replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
```

Comment: you should use replace() instead of replaceAll() as replaceAll() uses regex and "&amp;" is not a regex but a char sequence
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10827900/8958938

Answer (score 8):

The escaping happens in `org.jsoup.nodes.Entities`. 
This is the code in question

```
static void escape(StringBuilder accum, String string,
        Document.OutputSettings out, boolean inAttribute,
        boolean normaliseWhite, boolean stripLeadingWhite) {
    boolean lastWasWhite = false;
    boolean reachedNonWhite = false;
    EscapeMode escapeMode = out.escapeMode();
    CharsetEncoder encoder = out.encoder();
    CoreCharset coreCharset = CoreCharset.access$300(encoder.charset().name());
    Map map = escapeMode.getMap();
    int length = string.length();
    int codePoint;
    for (int offset = 0; offset < length; offset += Character.charCount(codePoint)) {
        codePoint = string.codePointAt(offset);

        if (normaliseWhite) {
            if (StringUtil.isWhitespace(codePoint)) {
                if ((stripLeadingWhite) && (!(reachedNonWhite)))
                    continue;
                if (lastWasWhite)
                    continue;
                accum.append(' ');
                lastWasWhite = true;
                continue;
            }
            lastWasWhite = false;
            reachedNonWhite = true;
        }

        if (codePoint < 65536) {
            char c = (char) codePoint;

            switch (c) {
            case '&':
                accum.append("&amp;");
                break;
            case ' ':
                if (escapeMode != EscapeMode.xhtml)
                    accum.append("&nbsp;");
                else
                    accum.append(c);
                break;
            case '<':
                if (!(inAttribute))
                    accum.append("&lt;");
                else
                    accum.append(c);
                break;
            case '>':
                if (!(inAttribute))
                    accum.append("&gt;");
                else
                    accum.append(c);
                break;
            case '"':
                if (inAttribute)
                    accum.append("&quot;");
                else
                    accum.append(c);
                break;
            default:
                if (canEncode(coreCharset, c, encoder))
                    accum.append(c);
                else if (map.containsKey(Character.valueOf(c)))
                    accum.append('&')
                            .append((String) map.get(Character.valueOf(c)))
                            .append(';');
                else
                    accum.append("&#x")
                            .append(Integer.toHexString(codePoint))
                            .append(';');
            }
        } else {
            String c = new String(Character.toChars(codePoint));
            if (encoder.canEncode(c))
                accum.append(c);
            else
                accum.append("&#x").append(Integer.toHexString(codePoint))
                        .append(';');
        }
    }
}
```

A quick way to do what you need would be to use something like this

```
String str = "http://exampl.com/designs.jsp?templateId=f348aaf2-45e4-4836-9be4-9a7e63105932&kind=123";
str = Jsoup.clean(str, Whitelist.basic());
System.out.println(str);
str = Parser.unescapeEntities(str, true);
System.out.println(str);
```

Another way would be to extend the above class and override the method that is causing the problem, but since it's visible only to the package (default visibility) this would mean that you have to download the source, change the visibility of the above method, and the override the class (so the method would be visible).

Comment: Thanks for your help. As a workround after applying Jsoup.clean() I am replacing &amp; with & using regex.

Comment: I believe this is a safier practice, but if that solved your problem then by all means use it. Since my answer doesn't solve your problem please post your answer and select it so the question can be considered closed.

Comment: using Parser.unescapeEntities(str, true) is the safer way than using a regex to replace.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @AlkisKalogeris. It saved me a lot of time.