# How to scrape currency formatted numbers in CSV file through Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have created a web **scraper** which **scrapes** data from a website and store it in CSV file. But, the problem is there is a column on the website which have currency formatted values which have amounts like **7,100** or **85,210**. When my code executed and **scrapes** the data, these values separated into two columns like 7 in one column and 100 in other column. Kindly, check the attached screenshots.
Code is as follows.

```
public class ComMarket_summary {

boolean writeCSVToConsole = true;
boolean writeCSVToFile = true;
boolean sortTheList = true;
boolean writeToConsole;
boolean writeToFile;
public static Document doc = null;
public static Elements tbodyElements = null;
public static Elements elements = null;
public static Elements tdElements = null;
public static Elements trElement2 = null;
public static String Dcomma = ",";
public static String line = "";
public static ArrayList<Elements> sampleList = new ArrayList<Elements>();

public static void createConnection() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "191.1.1.202");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    String tempUrl = "http://www.psx.com.pk/phps/mktSummary.php";
    doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(tempUrl), 1000);
    System.out.println("Successfully Connected");
}

public static void parsingHTML() throws Exception {

    for (Element table : doc.select("table.marketData")) {
        Elements tables = doc.select("table.marketData");
        table = tables.get(2);
        File fold = new File("C:\\market_smry.csv");
        fold.delete();
        File fnew = new File("C:\\market_smry.csv");
        for (Element trElement : table.getElementsByTag("tr")) {

            trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
            tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
            FileWriter sb = new FileWriter(fnew, true);

            //if (table.hasClass("marketData")) { //&&(tdElements.hasClass("tableHead")&&tdElements.hasClass("tableSubHead"))
            for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append(" , ");
                    sb.append(" \r\n ");
                }

                for (Iterator<Element> it2 = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    Element tdElement2 = it.next();
                    final String content = tdElement2.text();
                    if (it2.hasNext()) {

                        sb.append(formatData(content));
                        sb.append("   ,   ");
                        

                    }
                }

                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                sb.flush();
                sb.close();
            }

            System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));

        }
    }
}
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_MMM_d_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.US);
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_dd_MMM_yyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yy", Locale.US);

public static String formatData(String text) {
    String tmp = null;

    try {
        Date d = FORMATTER_MMM_d_yyyy.parse(text);
        tmp = FORMATTER_dd_MMM_yyyy.format(d);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        tmp = text;
    }

    return tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
    createConnection();
    parsingHTML();

}
```

[image]
[image]

Note: I am using windows 8, java version 1.8, jsoup 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving the value get rid of the comma by using `String.replace`

```
value = value.replace (",", "");
```

Comment: Is It possible to use replace() with HTML function?

Comment: I mean that the text **7,100**  is an HTML td Element text. So, can I use replace with tdElement like   
`final String content = tdElement2.text();
content = content.replace(","," ")`;

Comment: String content = tdElement2.text().replace (",", "");

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace` will get rid of your comma.  While there are several other similar functions (`replaceAll`, `replaceFirst`), `replace` will be slightly faster and is typically the best choice for a single character.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

And also: [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)