# Difference in behaviour between String.replaceAll() and StringUtils.replace()

Tags: java, string, replaceall, string-utils

I want to replace all single quotes with escaped single quotes. First I have tried with `String.replaceAll("\'", "\\'")` but it didn't worked. So, I have tried with `StringUtils.replace(String, "\'", "\\'")` which worked.

**Here is the code:**

```
String innerValue = "abc'def'xyz";
System.out.println("stringutils output:"+StringUtils.replace(innerValue, "\'", "\\'"));
System.out.println("replaceAll output:"+innerValue.replaceAll("\'", "\\'"));
```

**Expected Output:**

```
stringutils output:abc\'def\'xyz
replaceAll output:abc\'def\'xyz
```

**Actual Output:**

```
stringutils output:abc\'def\'xyz
replaceAll output:abc'def'xyz
```

I am just curious *Why `String.replaceAll` is not replacing `'` with `\'`?*

Comment: `String.replaceAll` uses regular expressions, where backslashes have special meaning. Use `replace` instead of `reaplceAll`.

Comment: Hint: when standard java library calls do not match up **your** expectations; then your expectations are **wrong**. The easy and simply way to fix that: RTFM. Seriously, don't assume that a method does this or that; just read its javadoc. Or: do some prior research, like **searching** this site before writing up a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single quote in `String`s (only in `char` values), and you need a double-double escape with the replacement value:

`innerValue.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")`

This is due to `replaceAll` taking regular expressions as arguments (the second parameter must support regular expressions for back references).

You can also use the `replace` idiom, since you're not using regular expressions:

`innerValue.replace("'", "\\'")`

**Note**

The `replace` method actually uses `replaceAll` behind the scenes, but transforms values into literals by invoking `Pattern.compile` with the `Pattern.LITERAL` flag, and `Matcher.quoteReplacement` on the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Java String Package replaceAll method expects RegularExpression as String parameter. 
Whereas Commons Lang StringUtils.replace expects String value.

We have to do double escape when it comes to native Java implementation. 
System.out.println("replaceAll output:"+innerValue.replaceAll("'", "\\'"));