# Data manipulation on all columns in Dataset with Java API

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After reading csv file in Dataset, want to remove spaces from String type data using Java API.

**Apache Spark 2.0.0**

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/pathToCsv/data.csv");
Dataset<String> dataset2 = dataset.map(new MapFunction<Row,String>() {

    @Override
    public String call(Row value) throws Exception {

        return value.getString(0).replace(" ", ""); 
        // But this will remove space from only first column
    }
}, Encoders.STRING());
```

By using `MapFunction`, not able to remove spaces from all columns.

But in `Scala`, by using following way in `spark-shell` able to perform desired operation.

```
val ds = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/pathToCsv/data.csv")
val opds = ds.select(ds.columns.map(c => regexp_replace(col(c), " ", "").alias(c)): _*)
```

Dataset `opds` have data without spaces. Want to achieve same in Java. But in Java API `columns` method returns `String[]` and not able to perform functional programming on Dataset.

**Input Data**

```
+----------------+----------+-----+---+---+
|               x|         y|    z|  a|  b|
+----------------+----------+-----+---+---+
|     Hello World|John Smith|There|  1|2.3|
|Welcome to world| Bob Alice|Where|  5|3.6|
+----------------+----------+-----+---+---+
```

**Expected Output Data**

```
+--------------+---------+-----+---+---+
|             x|        y|    z|  a|  b|
+--------------+---------+-----+---+---+
|    HelloWorld|JohnSmith|There|  1|2.3|
|Welcometoworld| BobAlice|Where|  5|3.6|
+--------------+---------+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: At which position you want to remove space, post a sample string and output you are expecting. You can use trim() function to remove leading and trailing white space.

Comment: @Ravikumar Want to remove space between the strings.

Comment: You can use regex for removing spaces between Strings, Just post a sample string and what output string you are expecting after removing spaces.

Comment: @Ravikumar check edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for (String col: dataset.columns) {
  dataset = dataset.withColumn(col, regexp_replace(dataset.col(col), " ", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following regex to remove white spaces between strings.

```
value.getString(0).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

About \s+ : match any white space character between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.
Instead of replace use replaceAll function.

More about replace and replaceAll functions [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Comment: this will remove space from first column only.

Comment: Print out value.getString(0) and post it so that to see whether string is multiline.

Comment: @mastersheel007 try this `value.getString(0).replaceAll("(?is)\\s+", "");`