# Catch Exceptions that are thrown on map function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am reading a file that It has some corrupt data.My file looks like this:

```
30149;E;LDI0775100  350000003221374461
30153;168034601 350000003486635135
```

The second line is how is supposed to look like.The first line has some extra characters in the first column. So I want to catch any exceptions that are thrown because of corrupt data.Not only the above Example. Below is the code where  I load my file into my RDD and try to catch exceptions in the map Function.

```
  val rawCustfile = sc.textFile("/tmp/test_custmap")

  case class Row1(file_id:Int,mk_cust_id: String,ind_id:Long)


   val cleanedcustmap = rawCustfile.map(x => x.replaceAll(";", 
 "\t").split("\t")).map(x => Try{
     Row1(x(0).toInt, x(1), x(2).toLong)}match {
      case Success(map) => Right(map)
      case Failure(e) => Left(e)
    }) 

    //get the good columns
   val good_rows=cleanedcustmap.filter(_.isRight)

    //get the errors
    val error=cleanedcustmap.filter(_.isLeft)

     good_rows.collect().foreach(println)

   error.collect().foreach(println)

   val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(cleanedcustmap.filter(_.isRight))
```

This   **good_rows.collect().foreach(println)**  prints:

```
 Right(Row1(30153,168034601,350000003486635135))
```

This  **error.collect().foreach(println)**   prints:

```
 Left(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "LDI0775100")
```

Everything works fine up to the point where I try to convert my rdd into a DataFrame. I get the following Exception:

```
 Name: scala.MatchError
 Message: Product with Serializable with 
 scala.util.Either[scala.Throwable,Row1] (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$RefinedType0)
    StackTrace: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:676)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:630)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:30)
    org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:414)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
    $line79.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:63)
    $line79.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:65)
    $line79.$read.<init>(<console>:67)
    $line79.$read$.<init>(<console>:71)
    $line79.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    $line79.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    $line79.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    $line79.$eval.$print(<console>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:361)
    org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:356)
    org.apache.toree.global.StreamState$.withStreams(StreamState.scala:81)
    org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:355)
    org.apache.toree.kernel.interpreter.scala.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:355)
    org.apache.toree.utils.TaskManager$$anonfun$add$2$$anon$1.run(TaskManager.scala:140)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My first question is, am I catching the exceptions the right way?. I want to get the errors because I want to print them. Is there a better way?. My second question is what am I doing wrong when converting my RDD into a DataFrama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I catching the exceptions the right way

Well, pretty much. Not sure the mapping of the `Try` into an `Either` is that improtant (you can think of a `Try` as a specialization of `Either` when the left-side type is a `Throwable`...) but both can work. Another issue you might want to fix is the use of `replaceAll` - it generates a **regex** out of the first argument (which you don't need in this case) and therefore is slower than `replace`, see [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall).

> what am I doing wrong when converting my RDD into a DataFrame

DataFrames only support a limited set of "standard" **types**:

- Primitives (e.g. Ints, Longs, Strings...)
- Arrays/Maps (of other supported types)
- Products (case classes or tuples of other supported types)

`Either` isn't one of these types (nor is `Try`), so it **can't be used in a DataFrame**.

You can solve it by:

1. Using only the "successful" records in your DataFrame (what use, other than logging, would the errors serve? Either way they should be handled separately):

   ```
   // this would work:
   val df = spark.createDataFrame(good_rows.map(_.right.get))
   ```
2. Converting the `Either` into a supported type, e.g. `Tuple2(Row1, String)` where the string is the error message, and where one of the values in the tuple is `null` (left is null for erroneous records, right is null for successful records)

Comment: Than very much for your reply. I apologize because I pasted the wrong line for when I create the DataFrame.  I did try your first suggestion, but I got the exception I mentioned above. I apologize if it caused any confusions. I ahve updated my question

Comment: _filtering_ on `isReight` isn't enough - it would only pass the `Either` instances with a right value, but these would still be instances of `Either`. Look closed and my suggested solution - it also _maps_ these records using `map(_.right.get)` which "unwraps" the `Either` instances into the underlying `Row1` values.

Comment: You could even do `good_rows = cleanedcustmap.collect{case Right(r) => r}` to avoid using the `right.get` method which is unsafe (not here, but in general, say if you forget to filter out `Left`s at some point).