# Replace all td's tags by th in a java String

Tags: java

I want to replace replace all "td" by "th" in this String

```
String head = "<tr>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n<td>Libelle</td>\n" 
                      + "<td>Nom Table</td>\n<td>Groupe</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n"
```

I tried to use :

```
head.replace("<td>", "<th>");
head.replace("</td>", "</th>");
```

but it doesn't working.

Can you help me ?

Comment: use replaceAll()

Comment: Use `head.replaceAll("td", "th");` you don't even need to specify opening/closing tags separately, unless you have `td` at other places in your string in addition to the tag

Comment: @Abubakkar it could be a bad idea to omit the `<>`, as it would then replace `td` found in words such as `outdoor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.replace(..)` will return resulting string, so you need set it back

```
head = head.replace("<td>", "<th>");
head = head.replace("</td>", "</th>");
```

Comment: You might want to use `head.replaceAll("<td\\b", "<th");`, in order to handle td tags with attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can either use the `replace` method and the `replaceAll` since you are not using any regular expression and you cannot have nested modifications (something like `"aaa".replace("a","b")`).

Moreover, the modified String is returned by the method (rather than implicit modification), so you should reassign the `head` value.

So, the solution should look like this:

```
String head = "<tr>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n<td>Libelle</td>\n<td>Nom Table</td>\n<td>Groupe</td>\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\n</tr>\n";

head = head.replaceAll("<td>", "<th>");
head = head.replaceAll("</td>", "</th>");

System.out.println(head);
```

**EDIT1:**

If you are willing to modify only these tags (and are always the same) you can use the `replace method`. Otherwise, you should use the `replaceAll` method since it can contain regex expressions. You can find more information on the difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` in [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Comment: head = head.replaceAll("td", "th"); will be enoughf

Comment: @abc123 but would risk replacing fragments of words such as `outdoor` transformed into `outhoor`

Comment: @Aaron so how about this head = head.replaceAll("td>", "th>");

Comment: I have found out that replace does modify all the appearances so I guessed what's the difference between the two methods. See the updated answer

Comment: @abc123 I don't really know where is the point on omitting the < since using the complete replace (<td>) will safely remove only the entries you need without worring of corner cases. If we could simplify the comparison to only one char I would admit it can have performance benefits. Otherwise I think it is not useful

Comment: @abc123 probably better but could still fail in some specific contexts : you could have custom tags ending in `td>`, or you could have human readable text containing `td>` getting replaced when they should not. I don't think the optimization of removing one `replaceAll` is worth the bother, but that's up to everyone. Actually the best solution would be to use an HTML parser, because you could argue that you might have some `<td>` tags in comments or cdata or scripts that shouldn't be replaced

Answer (score 0):

You can have one line as this.

```
 head = head.replaceAll("td>", "th>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that takes care of scenarios like empty `<td /><td/>` tags and when your `td` tags have attributes like `class=\"abc\"` :

```
String head  = ""<td class=\"abc\">outdoor</td><td />"";
head = head.replace("<td", "<th");
head = head.replace("</td", "</th");
System.out.println(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace methods returns a new string.

String s= "hi hi hi";

String f= s.replace("hi", "bye");

System.out.println(s+ "----" + f);

prints: hi hi hi----bye bye bye