# Howe to replace "{{" , "}}" in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to replace this character "{{" I have the following method that read the file.

```
public static void  readTxtFile(){
        File archivo = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            file= new File ("example.txt");
            fr = new FileReader (file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(!line.isEmpty()&& line.replace("{{player.id}}","201566"){
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if( null != fr ){
                    fr.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

With this method I read a txt file that contains a sequence of URL with the following format.

```
http://stats.nba.com/player/#!/{{ player.id }}/
```

I need to replace this content **{{ player.id }}** to **201566** , because I need to get the following format URL.

```
http://stats.nba.com/player/#!/201566/
```

I try to use with the traditional replace but I receive an error with boolean ... Could anyone help to me ?

Regards !

Comment: The code that you are showing does not attempt to replace anything. Show the actual code that causes the exception and provide the details of the error (copy paste the error message)

Comment: I forget the most important part ahahaha..wait a moment.

Comment: what error are you getting? linea where did you define this variable?

Comment: I update .. error translating.. I need a boolean to use replaceAll because I found it String there is the message.

Comment: sure you are getting an error with boolean.. why are you having the replace inside the if condition?

Comment: which is the best way to replace this ?

Comment: Since your conditional has the replace in it it fails the boolean.  Remember your conditional here takes if (value 1 && value 2) are true do the below. 
 Your replace won't evaluate to true...

Comment: "I receive an error with boolean" - please explain what exactly it means. Compiler error? Exception?

Comment: Is a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslashes

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\{\\{\\s*player\\.id\\s*\\}\\}", "201566");
```

This is a regular expression replace.
In a regular expression `.` would represent *any character*, whereas `\.` would represent a *period*. However as we are dealing with a normal String, the backslash of `\.` must be represented as two backslashes: `\\`.

`\s*` stands for any whitespace, as in your question a space was shown.

---

***Without regex:***

```
line = line.replace("{{ player.id }}", "201566");
```

Mind the spaces; they must be exactly like in the file.

Comment: Could you explain that a double backslash is actually an escape sequence for a single slash, and that single slashes before another character have meaning in regular expressions?

Comment: @vikingsteve quite correct; especially as the answer is trivial.

Comment: You're right that one has to use escape characters when using `replaceAll` , but could you explain why you prefer that over `replace` in this case?

Comment: Hello @JoopEggen , thanks for your answer and your explanation I have problem with Strings.

Comment: @ParkerHalo That was my first thought, though the spaces around `player.id` are a bit cumbersome. Added the non-regex version. Gave +1 for balance

Comment: Thanks for adding `replace(...)`. Although i like using regexes i feel that one reading this answer should know that there are several ways! +1

Answer (score 3):

This is a common mistake people tend to make while working with `String`s.

A Java-String is immutable. That means calling any method on a `String` will not change its contents. In your case that means:

```
String str = "...{{ foo }}...";
str.replace("foo", "bar");
```

will not result in `str == "...{{ bar }}..."`.

You'll have to assign the result of `replace(...)` to your `String`:

```
String str = "...{{ foo }}...";
str = str.replace("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void  readTxtFile(){
        File archivo = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            file= new File ("example.txt");
            fr = new FileReader (file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(!line.isEmpty()&& line.contains("{{player.id}}"){
                    line = line.replaceAll("\\{\\{\\s*player\\.id\\s*\\}\\}", "201566");
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if( null != fr ){
                    fr.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a fan of regex and I usually use regexr.com to do quick mockups.  Also after doing a quick look, I think it makes more sense.  Referring to this article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall