# Java String replaceAll Recursive behavior

Tags: java, replace, replaceall

Yesterday I was working on customized letters and memos. And I have made mapping keywords, like: [Dateofbirth], [Email], [Employee], [Salary] etc, which will be replace at the time of generation.

> Example: dear [Employee], your Current Salary is [Salary].

expected output:

> Output: dear John, your Current Salary is 12000.

I am using `replaceAll()` method here is a code.

```
   String str = "dear [Employee], your Current Salary is [Salary].";
        Map<String,String> vals = new HashMap<String,String>();
        vals.put("[Employee]","John");
        vals.put("[Salary]","12000");
        for(String key:vals.keySet()){
            str=str.replaceAll(key,vals.get(key));
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```

but the out is:

```
dJohn1200012000 [JohnJohnJohnJohnJohnJohnJohnJohn], JohnJohnu12000 Cu1200012000Johnnt 1200012000John1200012000John is [1200012000John1200012000John].
```

I was confused and Googled it and tried to make it correct, after that I changed `replaceAll()` with `replace()`

```
EX: str=str.replace(key,vals.get(key));
```

Now it is working fine. The question is Why replace all is doing such kind of behavior what is the core concept of `replaceAll()` and When to use `replace()` when to use `replaceAll()`.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Before going to your problem, I hope you know about [**String#format**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) that Java API have. With that you could simply write

```
String formattedString = String.format("dear %s, your Current Salary is %.2f", "John", 12000.45);
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

If you are doing that yourself for unavoidable situations, [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) treats the first parameter as a regex and not normal string to replace.

From docs of replaceAll.

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Since your parameter consists of `[`and`]` and they are matching with each character inside them.

It will work if you get rid of that `[]` and use any other special characters that are not meta characters for ex `#`.

```
    String str = "dear #Employee#, your Current Salary is #Salary#.";
    Map<String, String> vals = new HashMap<String, String>();
    vals.put("#Employee#", "John");
    vals.put("#Salary#", "12000");
    for (String key : vals.keySet()) {
        str = str.replaceAll(key, vals.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

gives you

```
dear John, your Current Salary is 12000.
```

Or simply use `replace()` as you said in the end.

Comment: +1, although it is worth mentioning that named placeholders are preferable to numbered or unnamed, position dependent placeholders like `%s` in many situations - e.g. messages intended to be translated to several languages.

Answer (score 2):

Let us have a look at javadocs of replace and replaceAll methods. Go to javadocs

### replace

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
>   replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
>   example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
>   "ba" rather than "ab".

So in simple words it replaces all the target words with replacement words.

### replaceAll

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.

To understand the given behavior, it is important to understand how regex works. Regex is a world in its own, however, we can discuss the given regex here.

Square brackets group a set of characters together. When invoked any character in that set gets matched.

For example: [abc] will match all the a, b and c. Since replaceAll uses regex to match, it would replace all a, b and c with replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

[`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) matches using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
[`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) matches using plain text.

The regex `[Employee]` is a [*character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any single character that is either `E`, `m`, `p`, `l`, `o`, `y` or `e`.

Answer (score 1):

replaceAll treats the first parameter as regex. So you need to escape the regex specific characters which in your case is [ and ]. They signify a set of characters hence the replaceAll is matching every character in that set and replacing with the value you provided. Try this instead to get the output you desire -

```
vals.put("\\[Employee\\]","John");
vals.put("\\[Salary\\]","12000");
```

Here we have escaped the special symbol [ and ] thus it no longer treats it as a set.

Working program - https://www.ideone.com/2hCbIM

Comment: Better, just avoid the char '[' and use something else instead of escaping it 1000 times.

Comment: I agree, but OP wanted to use that character.

Answer (score 0):

ReplaceAll compiles a regular expression and applies to the string. In this case, since your Key has '[' , it would match any of the characters present inside that. Hence, for each occurrence, it has replaced with the value

Answer (score 0):

**replaceAll()** expects a **regular expression** but **replace()** expects the exact string (char sequence). Regular expression requires its special characters escaped. So when it is required to simply replace a string use replace() method, and when it is required to match a regular expression and need to replace it, use replaceAll().

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall) may be useful for you to understand it.
Basically, there is only difference is `replaceAll` replaces all that strings which match `regex` provided as an argument and `replace()` replaces based on `chars`.