# Optimal way to replace \n \r and \t from a given String

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there a better way to do this in Java:

```
public static String clearLog(String message) {
    return message.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace( '\t' , ' ');
}
```

I know this creates 3 String object and I want to avoid it.

Comment: The cleanest way would probably to use [the `$` in a regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Comment: @Turing85: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) like this :

```
message.replaceAll("[\n\r\t]", " ");
```

because `replaceAll` uses regex, so you can create a class which holds these three characters `[\n\r\t]` replacing `\n` or `\r` or `\t` with a space.

Comment: Is replaceAll() better in my case? I have read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10827945  which mentions replace() is faster than replaceAll(). Please suggest.

Comment: @Ballaji I'm not too good to distinguish which one is performance but its clear that replaceAll use regex so it can be a little difference between the two ways, I would like to follow the solution of Andy or Sean Patrick instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex using a `char[]`:

```
char[] cs = message.toCharArray();
for (int a = 0; a < cs.length; ++a) {
  switch (cs[a]) {
    case '\n': case '\r': case '\t':
      cs[a] = ' ';
      break;
  }
}
return new String(cs);
```

This will likely be a lot faster than the regex approach because it's very simple code to execute: it doesn't involve the whole regex engine; but it's more verbose, less readable and less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use a Guava [`CharMatcher`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html).

```
String cleaned = CharMatcher.anyOf("\t\n\r").trimAndCollapseFrom(yourString, ' ');
```

CharMatcher is heavily optimized and will limit object creation. If you save the CharMatcher to a constant (you can, it's immutable), then this will only generate one interim Object, a `StringBuilder`.