# Java replaceAll not working

Tags: java, dictionary, replaceall

Map contents: key (#500 - #509); and there values

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : values.entrySet()) {
    if (line.contains(entry.getKey())) {
    line = line.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
    System.out.println(line);
    }
}

Original string #102=[#503+0.9775*#508-0.9775*#503]
output string #102=[2.0+0.9775*#508-0.9775*2.0]
```

"#508" is not replaced, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be you have a whitespace somwhere? What if you use `entry.getKey().trim()`?

Comment: Do you break/return in the if? Because all keys must be replaced. Debug. Also `replace` is safer, and as the entries are in any order, #12 -> 7 could replace #123 with 73.

Comment: You are printing after your first replacement. You should be printing after the loop is finished. I suggest you provide a [mcve] - **complete** and **verifiable**.

Comment: Yes, yes i was, thank you, long day at work, saved me.

Comment: **Code simply runs fine**, question should have been deleted already IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll() uses a regular expression to replace parts of strings. Try it with replace().

See [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Comment: `#508` does not contain any characters that have a special meaning in regexp, so this won't help. But it's a good idea nonetheless.

Comment: What i find interesting is that, there are multiple lines like that and the output is like this

Comment: #102=[3.0+0.9775*#508-0.9775*3.0]
#102=[3.0+0.9775*36.0-0.9775*3.0]

Comment: first line does not replace and on the second it does

Comment: @Cocos yeah so I overlooked your question when I answered... this is a weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) coupled with [`String#trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove any uncaught white space.

Comment: Hi chris and welcome. StackOverflow is (not supposed to be) a race to answer questions. Please take your time writing an answer and indicate *how it solves the problem*. So in this case explain why `#508` was not replaced. Marking your code and providing links to the documentation may earn you additional rep. (like above, click the edit to see what has changed).