# Java can't replace "{" with replaceAll method

Tags: java, string, methods, replaceall

We're using replaceAll method of String and we can't replace { in any string.
Our example:

Tried :

```
"some { string".replaceAll("{", "other string");
```

And the error is the following:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition   occurs

Open to any ideas! Maybe there is a workaround?!

Comment: You need to escape it `\{` should do the job

Comment: You might need to escape the character `{`. Try `.replaceAll("\\{", "other string");`

Comment: Unless you're trying to use regular expressions, you should be using `replace`, not `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 8):

Using replaceAll requires a [regular expression (regex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Try using the replace method instead of replaceAll

```
"some { string".replace("{", "other string");
```

or escape the special character in the regex using `\\`

```
"some { string".replaceAll("\\{", "other string");
```

Answer (score 5):

try with `replace()` like this

```
"some { string".replace("{", "other string");
```

or use `replaceAll` with following regex format

```
"some { string".replaceAll("\\{", "your string to replace");
```

Note : in the case of `replace()` the first argument is a character sequence, but in the case of `replaceAll` the first argument is regex

Comment: `replace` replaces all occurences, not only the first one. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence) @Korashen @Navneet Krishna

Comment: @Korashen Both `.replace` and `.replaceAll` replaces all occurrences.. `.replaceAll` is used with regexes, and `.replace` without. The name convention just sucks to be completely honest.. `.replaceAll` and `.replaceAllWithRegex` or something along those lines would have made more sense. Side note: There is also a  `.replaceFirst` method, which just like `.replaceAll` only accepts regexes, but will only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: Oh boy, you are right. Got something mixed up... deleted my comment as it is wrong. What was it then, that I had in mind...

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `{` as it has special meaning in the `regex`. Use :

```
String s = "some { string".replaceAll("\\{", "other string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the escape character `\\`:

```
"some { string".replaceAll("\\{", "other string");
```

The character `{` is reserved in regular expressions, thats why you have to escape it to match the literal. Alternatively, you can use `replace` to only consider a `CharSequence`, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape character "{" .

Try this :

```
"some { string".replaceAll("\\{", "other string");
```

Answer (score 1):

{ is an indicator to the regex engine that you are about to start a repetition indicator, like {2,4} which means '2 to 4 times of the previous token'.

But {f is illegal, because it has to be followed by a number, so it throws an exception.

You can do something like this

```
"some { string".replaceAll("\\{", "other string");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. replace:
   "xxx".replace("{","xxx")
2. replaceAll:
   "xxx".replace("\{","xxx")

[Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)