# how to remove \" from string in java?

Tags: java

```
String mp ="\"sameer\\\"raj\"";
```

I want `sameerraj` as out put i tried following but no luck.

```
mp = mp.replace("\"", "");

mp=mp.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

please help me out.

Comment: `mp = mp.replace("\"", "");` does work. It removes ```\"``` from your string. If you want to remove ```\\``` as well, you can also do `mp = mp.replace("\\","");`

Comment: What about `mp = mp.replace("\"", "").replace("\\", "")`

Comment: i got this out put sameer\raj

Comment: I'm getting your output `sameerraj` with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace it using `regex`,then you can use `replaceAll`

In order to replace `"`,you need to use `\` to escape it,so it will be `replaceAll("\"", "")`

In order to replace `\`,you need to use `\` to escape itself,but since `\` is a special character in regex,you need to use `\` to escape it again,so need to use 4 `\` in total,which is `replaceAll("\\\\", "")`

```
System.out.println(mp.replaceAll("\\\\", "").replaceAll("\"", ""));
```

output:

```
sameerraj
```

Comment: I'm affraid there is a little mistake. replace() function will replace all the occurrences of the given input. replaceAll() function is intended for regular expressions.

Comment: @Romansko you are right,thank you, the OP can choose other answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change `"\"sameer\\\"raj\"` to `"sameerraj"`, there are two characters you want to remove: `\"` and `\\`.

The easiest way to remove them is with `replace`.

```
mp = mp.replace("\"", "").replace("\\","");
```

You don't need `replaceAll`, because you don't need to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To remove `\"` you need to use escape characters for both of the characters.

Based on your example, this would do the trick:

```
String mp ="\"sameer\\\"raj\"";
mp = mp.replace("\"", "");
mp = mp.replace("\\", "");
```

(`mp = mp.replace("\"", "").replace("\\", "");` would work the same since these functions return a string.)

If you want to remove `\"` as a sequental block, you would type:

```
mp = mp.replace("\\\"", "");
```

The function will search for a substrings of `\"` and replace them with empty strings.

`replace()` function will replace all the occurrences of a given input.
`replaceAll()` function is intended for Regex.

You can read about the differences between `replace()` and `replaceAll()` here:
[Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Answer (score 0):

That will give you output sameerraj

```
String mp ="\"sameer\\\"raj\"";
String r = mp.replace("\\\"","");
String doe=r.replace("\"","");

System.out.println(doe);
```