# How can I add a character inside a Regular Expression which changes each time?

Tags: java, regex, string, character, replaceall

```java
String s = scan.nextLine();

s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(s.charAt(i) + "-");
    int temp = s.length();

    // this line is the problem
    s = s.replaceAll("[s.charAt(i)]", '');

    System.out.print((temp - s.length()) + "\n");
    i = -1;
}
```

I was actually using the above method to count each character.

I wanted to use `s.charAt(i)` inside  Regular Expression so that it counts and displays as below. But that line (line 10) doesn't work I know.

If it's possible how can I do it?

Example:

```
MALAYALAM (input)
          M-2
          A-4
          L-2
          Y-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation), so code written inside a string literal will not be executed; it is just part of the string. You would need to do something like `"[" + s.charAt(i) + "]"` instead to build the string programmatically.

But this is problematic when the character is a regex special character, for example `^`. In this case the character class would be `[^]`, which matches absolutely any character. You could escape regex special characters while building the regex, but this is overly complicated.

Since you just want to replace occurrences an exact substring, it is simpler to use the [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method which does not take a regex. Don't be fooled by the name `replace` vs. `replaceAll`; [both methods replace all occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall), the difference is really that `replaceAll` takes a regex but `replace` just takes an exact substring. For example:

```java
> "ababa".replace("a", "")
"bb"
> "ababa".replace("a", "c")
"cbcbc"
```