# Android mystery crash in libicuuc.so (utext_close)

Tags: android, str-replace, icu

Our Android game started to log weird crashes in Google Play ANRs & crashes section after the latest update.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000011be50  /system/lib64/libicuuc.so (utext_close_60+52)
  #01  pc 00000000001aa4c4  /system/lib64/libicui18n.so (icu_60::RegexPattern::zap()+212)
  #02  pc 00000000001aa560  /system/lib64/libicui18n.so (icu_60::RegexPattern::~RegexPattern()+36)
  #03  pc 0000000000094120  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x90000) (java.math.NativeBN.BN_copy [DEDUPED]+160)
  #04  pc 000000000018340c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x90000) (libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry$CleanerThunk.run+76)
  #05  pc 000000000040c754  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (sun.misc.Cleaner.clean+164)
  #06  pc 00000000001daa0c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueueLocked+236)
  #07  pc 00000000001dab2c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueuePending+172)
  #08  pc 00000000001d7b04  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x90000) (java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal+244)
  #09  pc 000000000015978c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x90000) (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+76)
  #10  pc 00000000002c1038  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #11  pc 000000000056ef88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #12  pc 00000000000d4204  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #13  pc 0000000000472fd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #14  pc 0000000000474090  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
  #15  pc 000000000049f684  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)
  #16  pc 0000000000083588  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #17  pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

The only changed code in the update that is somewhat relevant to this was in our analytics module where we are doing some string replacements:

```
private static String formatStringForAnalytics(String str) {
    if(str == null) {
        return "";
    }

    return str.replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll(":", "");
}
```

We haven't been able to reproduce the crash ourselves. So we have to wait a bit to make and release a new update where we disable this piece of code and see if the crash seems to disappear.

I just find weird that standard string replacements would cause something like this. Anyone else encountered similar crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually wrong string replacement function.

The API documentation says that [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches *the given regular*
>   *expression* with the given replacement.

I changed the code to use [`replace()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches *the literal target*
>   *sequence* with the specified literal replacement sequence.

This is actually what the code intended to do in first place. With this change the crashes disappeared.

It seems that when certain strings where logged into analytics the `replaceAll()` managed to somehow break the string and caused it to crash. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10827900/3012194) for question about differences between `replace()` and `replaceAll()` seems indeed to be very true in this case: **Using the wrong function can lead to subtle bugs.**