# replaceAll method in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

**why does it prints "I love work"? It has to be "I love pizza"**

```
void main() {      
    String lovePizza = 'i love work';
    lovePizza.replaceAll('work', 'pizza');
    print(lovePizza); // i love work       
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste code instead of posting screenshots of code.  Your question also contradicts what's shown in the screenshot.

Comment: "why does it prints "I love pizza"? It has to be "I love work"" – I am voting to close the question because I cannot reproduce the problem. The code prints "i love work" just like you say it should, which is also proved by the screenshot you posted, where you can *clearly* see that it prints "i love work".

Comment: I'm sorry . I was tired and I made a mistake I edited the post and ill try to work with stack overflow better .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between String replace() and replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall)

Answer (score 4):

Because [replaceAll](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) does not *change* the string, it creates a *new* string.

So at least you need:

```
lovePizza = lovePizza.replaceAll('work', 'pizza');
```

Answer (score 3):

there is a need to save replaceAll result into a new variable because it returns a new value

```
void main() {
  
String loveWork = 'i love work';
String lovePizza = loveWork.replaceAll('work', 'pizza');
print(lovePizza); // i love pizza  
  
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/e5742a082832eb3f3739e19946538035?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You instead need to use the result of `lovePizza.replaceAll()` since it does not change the original `lovePizza` String but instead returns a new String.

```
void main() {
  
String lovePizza = 'i love work';
lovePizza = lovePizza.replaceAll('work', 'pizza');
print(lovePizza);
  
  
}
```