# Cannot replace ${} variable in Java

Tags: java

I have a function in which I am trying to replace ${schema} in a file with a variable pass into the parameter.

So for example

```
sample.sql
insert into ${schema}.table values (1,2,3);
```

What i want to achieve when running this function is

```
sample.sql
insert into public.table values (1,2,3);
```

So my function does below

```
public static void setvariable_java(String scriptName, String replaceString){
    File ftmp = new File("./src/tempsqlStatements/" + scriptName + ".sql");
    String pattern = "\\$\\{schema\\}";
    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ftmp));
        String ln;
        while((ln = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            ln = ln.replace("${schema}", "");
            System.out.println(ln);
        }
        
    }catch (Exception s){
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I am running the function

```
setvariable_java("sample","public")
```

However, in my sql file, the ${schema} is not getting replaced by sample and it is still giving me when i println.

```
insert into ${schema}.table values (1,2,3);
```

Is there anything Im doing wrong?

Edit: I am able to successfully write to the file using filewriter.

```
public static void setvariable_java(String scriptName, String searchString,  String replaceString){
        FileWriter writer = null;
        String oldContent = "";
        try{
            
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ftmp));
            String ln;
            
            while((ln = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                ln  = ln.replace("${schema}", replaceString);
                //System.out.println(ln);
                oldContent = oldContent + ln + System.lineSeparator();
                
            }
            System.out.println(oldContent);
            writer = new FileWriter (ftmp);
            writer.write(oldContent);
            writer.close();

            
        }catch (Exception s){
            s.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Comment: Try `ln = ln.replaceAll(pattern, "");` .

Comment: Try this : BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ftmp));

Comment: You also don't even use `replaceString` anywhere, you need to use it in your `replaceAll` or `replace` call.  As another note, you can just use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, they both replace all occurrences but `replaceAll` is for regex arguments.  See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827872/difference-between-string-replace-and-replaceall#:~:text=When%20you%20want%20to%20replace,a%20string%20use%20replaceAll().).

Comment: What is `f`? Is it a typo and actually supposed to be `ftmp`?

Comment: `replace` doesn't work in-place because Strings are immutable. It creates a new String, so you need to reassign the result back to `ln`

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Method names should go camelCase(), too. No "_" in them.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use regex replace when you don't need regex!

```
ln = ln.replace("${schema}", replaceString);
```

Notes:

- `replace()` still replaces all instances, but does a plain text match (not a regex match)
- you must assign the result of the replace to the variable. Strings are immutable - `replace()` (or `replaceAll()`) returns a new String.

Comment: Ok I am able to printlin out correctly when I do a system.out.println but still the file is not being updated.

Comment: @Adam What is `ftmp`? Have you checked where the output is being written?

Comment: yes the file is being written out to the directory i wanted. File ftmp = new File("./src/tempsqlStatements/" + scriptName + ".sql");